# Prototype / Mootools conflict question

Tags: jquery, mootools, prototypejs, conflict

So I have a page that uses both Prototype and Mootools AJAX scripts.

There is much more Mootools that Prototype, so I'm wondering if Prototype has a function similar to jQuery's `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` that I can use to redefine the $ alias for Prototype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The newest version of MooTools has a no conflict mode. Unfortunately, Prototype does not, which means that the `$` will have to be bound to Prototype.

To enable the Dollar Safe Mode, upgrade your version of MooTools and make sure you include MooTools after Prototype.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js" />
```

After doing so, `$` will be bound to Prototype. In MooTools scripts, replace all `$` references to `document.id`.

```
// Before
var X = new Class({
    initialize: function(element){
        this.element = $(element);
    }
});


// After
var X = new Class({
    initialize: function(element){
        this.element = document.id(element);
    }
});
```

or you can use a closure:

```
(function(){

    var $ = document.id;

    this.X = new Class({
        initialize: function(element){
            this.element = $(element);
        }
    });

})();
```

More information about the Dollar Safe Mode is available in MooTools' blog:

> http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping Prototype had something similar to this since it's by far the smaller implementation, but naturally, one is never so lucky.

Comment: While I do agree that you do not want a 200 kb (compressed) library, MooTools' 67 kb compressed is very respectable. Don't base your choice on size, but on functionality. MooTools does everything Prototype does and I would recommend to drop Prototype. Also, use the website to do a custom build of MooTools and remove anything you do not need.

Answer (score 3):

I have a really simple solution:

```
<script src='mootools.js'></script>
<script>$moo = $; delete ($);</script>
<script src='prototype.js></script>



<script>

(function ($){


//here you can use $ of moo tools

})($moo);


//here you can use $ of prototype


</script>
```