# mootools's slideshow doesnt work when prototype.js is included in document

Tags: javascript, mootools, prototypejs, conflict

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prototype / Mootools conflict question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722791/prototype-mootools-conflict-question)

mootools's slideshow noobslide doesnt work when prototype.js is included in the document. Otherwise works fine!

How do I resolve this conflict ?

Answer (score 1):

Mootools and Prototype collide fairly badly, because they're both trying to do similar things.

There is one work around documented here:

[Prototype / Mootools conflict question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722791/prototype-mootools-conflict-question)

But it doesn't look like a fun fix really.

Comment: +1 though I would not recommend the workaround. Both are `prototypical` so you cannot hope to get them going with any degree of certainty that the app will run as expected. This is not at all about the mere war over the $, it's about which framework's `.addEvent` or `.addClass` runs (and then there is IE6/7/8, which does not allow for `Element.prototype` changes so the methods are added on the elements - at least by mootools). Also, arrays/collections, which one's `.each` and so forth. `Function.prototype` as well. Time to rethink your framework inclusion...